# Is there possible to directly save html as pdf instead of opening print preview and save as pdf?

Tags: html, pdf, printing

I have a printable version of html, i want it to save as pdf instead ask user to print.

```
window.print();
```

Right now, i am using Google chrome. When every time want to save the html as pdf, need change "destination" to Microsoft Print to PDF. I want skip these steps and directly save as PDF. Is there possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form class="form" style="max-width: none; width: 1005px;">  


        <h2 style="color: #0094ff">Hello</h2>  
         <table>  
            <tbody>  
                <tr>  
                    <th>Company</th>  
                    <th>Contact</th>  
                    <th>Country</th>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>  
                    <td>Maria Anders</td>  
                    <td>Germany</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>  
                    <td>Francisco Chang</td>  
                    <td>Mexico</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Ernst Handel</td>  
                    <td>Roland Mendel</td>  
                    <td>Austria</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Island Trading</td>  
                    <td>Helen Bennett</td>  
                    <td>UK</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>  
                    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>  
                    <td>Canada</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>  
                    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>  
                    <td>Italy</td>  
                </tr>  
            </tbody>  
        </table>  

    </form> 
   <style type="text/css">
      table {  
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;  
            border-collapse: collapse;  
            width: 100%;  
        }  

        td, th {  
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;  
            text-align: left;  
            padding: 8px;  
        }  

        tr:nth-child(even) {  
            background-color: #dddddd;  
        }
   </style>
      <input type="button" id="create_pdf" value="Generate PDF"> 
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script> 

   <script>  
    (function () {  
        var  
         form = $('.form'),  
         cache_width = form.width(),  
         a4 = [595.28, 841.89]; // for a4 size paper width and height  

        $('#create_pdf').on('click', function () {  
            $('body').scrollTop(0);  
            createPDF();  
        });  
        //create pdf  
        function createPDF() {  
            getCanvas().then(function (canvas) {  
                var  
                 img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),  
                 doc = new jsPDF({  
                     unit: 'px',  
                     format: 'a4'  
                 });  
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);  
           //   doc.save('Bhavdip-html-to-pdf.pdf');  
            //window.open();



            doc.output('datauristring');        //returns the data uri string
            //opens the data uri in current window
            var blob = doc.output("blob");
            window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
           // doc.output('dataurlnewwindow'); 

                form.width(cache_width);  
            });  
        }  

        // create canvas object  
        function getCanvas() {  
            form.width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');  
            return html2canvas(form, {  
                imageTimeout: 2000,  
                removeContainer: true  
            });  
        }  

    }());  
</script>  
<script>  
    /* 
 * jQuery helper plugin for examples and tests 
 */  
    (function ($) {  
        $.fn.html2canvas = function (options) {  
            var date = new Date(),  
            $message = null,  
            timeoutTimer = false,  
            timer = date.getTime();  
            html2canvas.logging = options && options.logging;  
            html2canvas.Preload(this[0], $.extend({  
                complete: function (images) {  
                    var queue = html2canvas.Parse(this[0], images, options),  
                    $canvas = $(html2canvas.Renderer(queue, options)),  
                    finishTime = new Date();  

                    $canvas.css({ position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0 }).appendTo(document.body);  
                    $canvas.siblings().toggle();  

                    $(window).click(function () {  
                        if (!$canvas.is(':visible')) {  
                            $canvas.toggle().siblings().toggle();  
                            throwMessage("Canvas Render visible");  
                        } else {  
                            $canvas.siblings().toggle();  
                            $canvas.toggle();  
                            throwMessage("Canvas Render hidden");  
                        }  
                    });  
                    throwMessage('Screenshot created in ' + ((finishTime.getTime() - timer) / 1000) + " seconds<br />", 4000);  
                }  
            }, options));  

            function throwMessage(msg, duration) {  
                window.clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);  
                timeoutTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {  
                    $message.fadeOut(function () {  
                        $message.remove();  
                    });  
                }, duration || 2000);  
                if ($message)  
                    $message.remove();  
                $message = $('<div ></div>').html(msg).css({  
                    margin: 0,  
                    padding: 10,  
                    background: "#000",  
                    opacity: 0.7,  
                    position: "fixed",  
                    top: 10,  
                    right: 10,  
                    fontFamily: 'Tahoma',  
                    color: '#fff',  
                    fontSize: 12,  
                    borderRadius: 12,  
                    width: 'auto',  
                    height: 'auto',  
                    textAlign: 'center',  
                    textDecoration: 'none'  
                }).hide().fadeIn().appendTo('body');  
            }  
        };  
    })(jQuery);  

</script>
```

Comment: @Crazy apply my new code and chrome pop up blocker allow

Comment: How do you set the margin for page? I just use a simple one like http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/74gtwghw/ to achieve what i need. I only can set margin left and top, how to set for all margin? Thanks